# what is this? And how do i access it? Using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

In a lot of apps I use, I see this UI Activity Indicator View? Is it made manually, or does apple have a SDK for it? I know how to make the normal one, but how do I access the one with a black background?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The title of this question is so generic and could be made much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You already know that it's a UIActivityIndicatorView.

You can drop it into your view in a Storyboard or XIB file, or you can add it programatically.  It's part of the iOS SDK.

To change the style, there are [UIActivityIndicatorStyles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle) you can set when calling ['initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:'](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivityIndicatorView/initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:) programatically or in the attribute section of your storyboard/xib file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a custom spinner, created with [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

> MBProgressHUD is an iOS drop-in class that displays a translucent HUD
>   with an indicator and/or labels while work is being done in a
>   background thread. The HUD is meant as a replacement for the
>   undocumented, private UIKit UIProgressHUD with some additional
>   features.

A basic use:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // do your stuff while spinner is showing

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES]; // stop the spinner
    });
});
```

For use this in Swift see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881625/how-to-use-mbprogresshud-with-swift).

Answer (score -2):

it's the UIActivityIndicatorView provided by iOS SDK, and we can set background color of UIActivityIndicatorView

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```