# Show activity indicator while website is loading

Tags: ios, webkit, swift2

i searchin for a ios 8 swift 2 solution for showing an activity indicator while my website is loading in the background.

at the moment, i have this code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var url = "http://www.google.de"
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request) }
```

Problem is, the view controlle is the whole time white while the webseite is loading. i hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an activity indicator to the view of the contoller. Check out this tutorial: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/activity-indicator-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: that is clear - but how can i check if the website is finish with loading?

Comment: webView delegate triggers a webViewDidFinishLoad method. If you assign your viewController as the delegate of the webView, and implement webViewDidFinishLoad method in your viewController, it will call that method once webView finished loading the page :)

Comment: check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad:

Answer (score 2):

Drag the Activity Indicator View  to the ViewController class and add the following code after this line // **webView.loadRequest(request)** // or which ever line loads the url.

**activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()**

To stop animation use

**activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()**

You can also use a stop and start button or any other Action .

Answer (score 1):

you can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) library for loading indicator in swift, also you can check [How to use MBProgressHUD with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881625/how-to-use-mbprogresshud-with-swif) if it's working in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish, refer to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65136127/2131039

---

### Here it's anyways (just in case if it got deleted)

Tested in Swift 5, you can use the following simple extension:

```swift
// Activity Indicator Extension
var vSpinner : [UIView] = []

extension UIViewController {
    func showSpinner(onView : UIView) {
        let spinnerView = UIView.init(frame: onView.bounds)
//        spinnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, alpha: 0.9)
        let ai = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(style: .medium)
        ai.startAnimating()
        ai.center = spinnerView.center
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinnerView.addSubview(ai)
            onView.addSubview(spinnerView)
        }
        
        vSpinner.append(spinnerView)
    }
    
    func removeSpinner() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            vSpinner.popLast()?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Within your async task use these two handy boys:

`showSpinner(onView: self.view)` Remember to replace *self.view* with any kind of view you desire

`self.removeSpinner()` Remove the loading indicator: