# How can i use activity indicator when a user registers or login messageView using swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, xcode8, uiactivityindicatorview

How can i use activity Indicator in the following code when a user registers or logs in the message view.

The Code below is a loginViewController which handles the login and Registeration of the User.

so, How can i use Activity Indicator View or Progress view PROGRAMATICALLY whenever a user hits the Login or Register Button .

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {

        var messagesController: MessagesController?

    let inputsContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 209, g:238, b:252).withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

    lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 45, b: 85)
        button.setTitle("Register", for: UIControlState())
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegister), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()


    func handleLoginRegister() {
        if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            handleLogin()
        } else {
            handleRegister()
        }
    }

    func handleLogin() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
            print("Form is not valid")
            return
        }

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }

            //successfully logged in our user

            self.messagesController?.fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitle()

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        })

    }

 // TextField, EmailTextField, PasswordTextField, seperator view

    let nameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Name"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()

    let nameSeparatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let emailTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Email"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()

    let emailSeparatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Password"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()


    lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "backslash_inc02main")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return imageView
    }()


    lazy var loginRegisterSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }()

    func handleLoginRegisterChange() {
        let title = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState())

        // change height of inputContainerView, but how???
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.constant = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 100 : 150

        // change height of nameTextField
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 0 : 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
        nameTextField.isHidden = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0

        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor = emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 149, b: 0)

        self.view.addBackground()
        view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)
        view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)
        view.addSubview(profileImageView)
        view.addSubview(loginRegisterSegmentedControl)


        setupInputsContainerView()
        setupLoginRegisterButton()
        setupProfileImageView()
        setupLoginRegisterSegmentedControl()
    }

    func setupLoginRegisterSegmentedControl() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true
    }

    func setupProfileImageView() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    }

    var inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var nameTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var emailTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    func setupInputsContainerView() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor = inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameSeparatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(emailTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(emailSeparatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(passwordTextField)

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        nameTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        nameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

        nameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        nameSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        emailTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        emailTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor = emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)

        emailTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        emailSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        emailSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        passwordTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
    }

    func setupLoginRegisterButton() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        loginRegisterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }



}
```

Comment: You can use MPProgressHud library. It's in Objective-C and you can add using Briding header. Please check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881625/how-to-use-mbprogresshud-with-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show activity indicator, first declare it at class level and then initialize it.

```
 var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

Then in your viewdidLoad() method, initialize activityIndicator.

```
 activityIndicator =  UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
 activityIndicator.center = view.center
 activityIndicator.isHidden = true
 self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```

You can write two methods to start and stop activity indicator in your view controller as:

```
  func displayActivityIndicatorView() -> () {
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.activityIndicator)
    self.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
  }

   func hideActivityIndicatorView() -> () {
     if !self.activityIndicator.isHidden{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true

        }
    }

  }
```

Now start activity indicator just after validating the login data and before hitting the login API as:

```
 func handleLogin() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
    }
    //start activity indicator
    self. displayActivityIndicatorView()
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "")
            //stop activity indicator
            self. hideActivityIndicatorView()
            return
        }

        //successfully logged in our user
            //stop activity indicator
            self. hideActivityIndicatorView()
        self.messagesController?.fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitle()

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    })

}
```

Comment: can you share the full code from declaration to initializing activityIndicator, as mine is showing error which i am trying to fix. and Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am getting an error " use of undeclared type 'UIActivityIndicator'  but i have declared the UIActivityIndicator.  any fix?

Comment: make sure you have declared it outside of all methods.

Comment: can u send the whole code( after editing) so that i can verify where i have been making the mistake as it is really bothering me now....thank you

Comment: write this line, var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicator! , outside of the viewDidLoad() method. Then if follow this answer, everything should work.

Comment: i misspelled the type of activityIndicator , i have edited it. Correct the declaration of activityIndicator, it should work now @yash

Comment: Yeah...Thank u!!..... is there a way through which i can show some text with activityIndicator View when LoggingIn or Registering?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Create activity indicator somewhere in your code. Specially in **viewDidLoad**
if you want to create it programmatically or if you want to show activity indicator with an alert design in programmatically.

**Step 2:** To show activity indicator

There is a button like **login** or **register** . There you will start the to show the activity indicator and start it to animate.

**Step 3:** To hide activity indicator

You will hide activity indicator in **FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn.....** completion handler for login. just like

```
[indicator stopAnimating];
[indicator isHidden:YES];
```

There are two cases in that login method. one is error and the other is successful. Its better to show an error alert to the user or something else.
Hope you will find this solution helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:5, width:50, height:50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
     loadingIndicator.color = UIColor(red: 255.0/255, green: 65.0/255, blue: 42.0/255,alpha : 1.0)
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

///dismisss///
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```