# How to matching loading progress with JGProgressHUD

Tags: ios, swift, progress, hud

I want to ask how to matching loading with JGProgressHUD when you are waiting for a request or when is loading getting location info? The documentation is written in objective-c and I don't really understand objc.

thank you.

Comment: Example on this link are in swift https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD/tree/master/Examples

Comment: You can use `MBProgressHUD` instead of `JGProgressHUD`, https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD How to implement/use in swift please visit this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881625/how-to-use-mbprogresshud-with-swift